# How to load COM DLL at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, com, vb6

I have a VB6 COM DLL. I want to use it from C++. I know how to register it, generate a tlb file from the DLL, and #import it in C++.

I'd like however, to load and use DLLs like this dynamically, at runtime, without knowing them in advance. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to avoid registering them, or avoid generating the type library and #importing? Or both (which I'm not sure is possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need to get the question clearer.

Sometimes, you do know the COM interface upfront, just not the implementation. In that case, you can create a dummy implementation of the interface and #import that. At runtime, you'd still register the real component, get an object from it (via `CoCreateInstance` probably) and store that in an appropriate smart pointer.

With VB6, it's a bit less direct. This adds a level of indirection. Read up on `IDispatch`. You need to get that known interface to describe an unknown interface. That way, the unknown interface can be obtained at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, You need at least some common interface (so you known what to call in the C++ side).

I'd do something like:

1. Define a common interface (in its own DLL/TLB)
2. Implement this interface in one or more COM servers
3. Import this interface in the C++ side (let's call it **client**)
4. Define a way to pass the **progid** of the COM server you want to work with (load dynamically) in the client.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these two MSDN articles about ***Registration-Free Activation of COM Components***:

- [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973913(v=msdn.10))
- [Escape DLL Hell: Simplify App Deployment with ClickOnce and Registration-Free COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/april/simplify-app-deployment-with-clickonce-and-registration-free-com)

There also have been some similar question here on StackOverflow:

- [Generate manifest files for registration-free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/)
- [Windows/C++: how to use a COM dll which is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466138/)