# Use an unregistered COM dll in Classic ASP

Tags: dll, com, asp-classic

I have a strange situation and I am unable to find a solution for this. I am working on a publically accessible Classic ASP site. I don't have access to the server or IIS but I have FTP access to it.

Now I want to reference a COM dll (not a .Net dll) to one of the asp pages. And then use it to create objects like:

```
Server.CreateObject(...)
```

I know about **using RegSvr32 to register the dll** or **placing it into C:\Windows\system32**, but I am unable to do so as **I don't have access to the server**.

I tried to place the dll with the asp file but it did not work.

Is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: Might be some tracks for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466138/windows-c-how-to-use-a-com-dll-which-is-not-registered

Comment: All you can do is contact your server tech support and ask them to install the component.  If it's shared hosting there may be something which does the same job already installed, eg a lot of Classic ASP packages come with Persits ASPUpload

Answer (score 1):

I understand the situation, and have been there before.

However, there is no way (that I am aware of) to get it done that isn't related to a security/setup flaw that would make me want to change my hosting provider.